# How to generate weighted mean plot using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, weighted-average

I was able to generate average movement of variable **lny_10** using the following code:

```
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = year, y = lny_10)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1991, 1997, 2000, 2003, 2011), lim = c(1991, 2011)) + theme_bw() + stat_summary(geom = "line", fun.y = mean)
```

[image]

On the same plane, I want to just add another trend line of **weighted average** of the same variable where the weights are determined by the **sum of lnl** in each industry so that this new trend line reflects the weight of lnl in a certain industry (either Manufacturing or Fishery). In other words, if the sum in manuf. sector is greater than that of fishery industry, then more weight would be assigned to the average of lny_10 in manufacturing sector.

Any help would be appreciated!

The sample data is the following:

```
structure(list(firmid = structure(c("016090", "002070", "009270", 
"007700", "005800", "014990", "001460", "001460", "005800", "014990"
), format.stata = "%-6s"), year = structure(c(1992, 1992, 1992, 
1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1993, 1993, 1993), format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    lny_10 = structure(c(24.0853042602539, 24.2753143310547, 
    24.1893978118896, 22.7417297363281, 24.0077304840088, 24.0432777404785, 
    24.6088676452637, 24.6565208435059, 23.8993816375732, 24.2486095428467
    ), format.stata = "%9.0g"), lnl = structure(c(6.81234502792358, 
    7.56631088256836, 7.19368600845337, 5.48063898086548, 7.38398933410645, 
    6.63331842422485, 7.81439971923828, 7.72621250152588, 7.33040523529053, 
    6.74288082122803), format.stata = "%9.0g")),  industry = structure(c("Manufacturing", "Manufacturing", "Manufacturing", 
    "Manufacturing", "Manufacturing","Fishery", "Fishery","Fishery","Fishery","Fishery"), label = "classification", format.stata = "%-51s")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Could you not calculate a weighted mean separately? 
```df %>%
  group_by(year)%>%
  summarise(lny_wmean = weighted.mean(lny_10,lnl))```

I'm a little confused as the data did not reproduce your plot.

Comment: @mlcyo, thanks, I slightly modified the code. The tricky part is that I should consider the weighted mean of lnl by industry (manufacturing and fishery). So if the weight of manufacturing industry is higher than the other, more weight will be imposed on the mean of lny_10 which belong to manufacturing industry. I hope it is clear to you.

Comment: Hmmm can you hust group_by year and industry then?

Comment: @mlcyo, sorry could you a bit specify further, if possible with the relevant codes?

Comment: Sure, does this give you what you need? ```df %>%   group_by(year, industry)%>%   summarise(lny_wmean = weighted.mean(lny_10,lnl))```

Comment: @mlcyo, thanks based on your comment, I tried: 
p22 = df %>%   group_by(year, industry)%>%   
  summarise(lny_wmean = weighted.mean(lny_10, lnl)) %>% 
  ggplot() + stat_summary(geom = "line", fun = mean) + theme_bw() + geom_line(df, mapping = aes(x = year , y = lny_10)) +  geom_line(df, mapping = aes(x = year, y = lny_wmean)), but plot does not work. Any idea?

Comment: Hi, I think there were a few problems with how you called some attributes. This works, by joining the weighted mean back to the original dataframe: ```dfweights<- df %>%   group_by(year, industry)%>%   summarise(lny_wmean = weighted.mean(lny_10,lnl)) 

df2 <- left_join(df, dfweights, by = c("year", "industry"
))


df2 %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  stat_summary(aes(x = year, y = lny_10), geom = "line", fun = mean, colour = "red") +
  theme_bw() + 
  geom_line(aes(x = year , y = lny_10), colour = "blue") +   
  geom_line(aes(x = year, y = lny_wmean), colour = "green")```

Comment: @mlcyo, thanks the code above generates the following error: Error: Join columns must be present in data. x Problem with `year` and `industry`. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Are the year and industry columns present in both df and dfweight?

Comment: @mlcyo, no only in df.

Comment: Did this bit run completely? ```dfweights <- df %>%   group_by(year, industry)%>%   summarise(lny_wmean = weighted.mean(lny_10,lnl))```

Comment: @mlcyo, I think so. after running, `colnames(dfweights)` gives `[1] "lny_wmean`.

Comment: I get three columns from that code. Are you using dplyr group_by and summarise? Try this,. Also, there is an error in your structure command above, but I assume your df isn't made using that. ```dfweights<- df %>%   dplyr::group_by(year, industry)%>%   dplyr::summarise(lny_wmean = weighted.mean(lny_10,lnl))```

Comment: @mlcyo, it works! Many thanks!

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate the weights separately by year and industry and join them back to the original dataframe before plotting.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

dfweights <- df %>%   
   group_by(year, industry) %>%   
   summarise(lny_wmean = weighted.mean(lny_10,lnl))  

df2 <- left_join(df, dfweights, by = c("year", "industry"))   

df2 %>%    
   ggplot() +    
   stat_summary(aes(x = year, y = lny_10), geom = "line", fun = mean, colour = "red") +   
   theme_bw() +    
   geom_line(aes(x = year , y = lny_10), colour = "blue") +      
   geom_line(aes(x = year, y = lny_wmean), colour = "green")
```